# Localhost, [::1], and mapped hosts in etc/hosts work, but 127.0.0.1 does not

Tags: node.js, curl, express, networking, localhost

The great mystery.  I have an Express/Node (v4.2.2) JS app running on OS X El Capitan.  The app is running on port 4444.  If I run the app, I'm able to get the proper response back with the following commands:

`curl localhost:4444` -> Works

`curl [::1]:4444` -> Works

`curl api.q.com:4444` -> Works

However, I have a problem with:

`curl 127.0.0.1:4444` -> **Doesn't Work; Responds with** `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

`127.0.0.1:4444` fails in all browsers as well. Even more astonishing, `api.q.com:4444` works in all browsers **EXCEPT** for Chrome.

My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost web.q.com api.q.com qrm.q.com fhr.q.com

::1 localhost

fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

I've tried resetting my `/etc/hosts` file back to the default and flushed my DNS cache.  I have a feeling it might be the app, but I'm not sure what the cause could be.  Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried removing ::1 localhost from your host file all together? I know you shouldn't have to but it has worked for me in the past.

Comment: See answer.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it had something to do with a Linux VM I set up in Virtual Box.  My `/etc/hosts` file was the same on that VM (maybe that was the issue?).

I disabled the VM and everything worked again.  I have no idea what the cause was, but I'm going to close this question.  If anyone else has this issue, I can only suggest look at any VMs you may have running locally.  Thanks again!